# I have a UDP stream of raw data. What are some steps I can take to figure out what it is?

Tags: udp, streaming, wireshark

Using Wireshark, I captured a stream of UDP packets from a smart device. A few details:

1. The device directly sends these packets to my cellular device, communicating with an app. There's no cloud service in between.
2. The device is sending video/audio stream, but I'm unsure of the protocol since there is no header beyond raw UDP. I have tried decoding it as RTP, but again, due to the lack of a header, Wireshark isn't able to interpret it as such.
3. The stream is unencrypted; when I cover the camera and muffle the microphone, the data contains a lot of `b0`s.

What are some things I can check to find out what protocol this stream is encoded in?

Comment: What's the device? What's the app? It's much easier to determine reasonable protocols for network traffic than guess based upon bytes.

Comment: @RossJacobs Specifically, this: https://roybirobot.com/
It's a smart toy device that has a built-in camera and microphone. The toy connects directly to an open socket for the mobile app when the camera is enabled. For other features, there's pretty standard TCP/IP packets being sent to a cloud server, which the app also talks to.

Comment: A quick google search doesn't reveal the network protocol for this device. If you want to iterate over existing audio/video protocols to check which one it might be, that would be a method. It could easily be a proprietary or encrypted protocol and you wouldn't know. Short of someone familiar with this device chiming in, determining the protocol is a good exercise in familiarizing yourself with A/V protocols.